# Higher kinded types as type parameters

Tags: kotlin, higher-kinded-types

I have a generic sealed class, used to represent either single values or pairs of values (split before and after a certain event):

```
sealed class Splittable<T>

data class Single<T>(val single: T) : Splittable<T>()

data class Split<T>(val before: T, 
                    val after : T) : Splittable<T>()
```

I would like to define data classes that are generic (parameterizable) over `Splittable`, so that the properties of the class must **either be all Single or all Split.** I thought this would do it:

```
data class Totals<SInt : Splittable<Int>>(
    val people : SInt,
    val things : SInt
)

val t1 = Totals(
    people = Single(3),
    things = Single(4)
)

val t2 = Totals(
    people = Split(3, 30),
    things = Split(4, 40)
)
```

But I was wrong, because it allows invalid combinations:

```
val WRONG = Totals(
    people = Single(3),
    things = Split(4, 40)
)
```

Moreover, what if my class has more than one basic type, for instance both `Int` and `Boolean`? How do I write the generic signature?

```
data class TotalsMore<S : Splittable>(
    val people : S<Int>,
    val things : S<Int>,
    val happy  : S<Boolean>
)

val m1 = TotalsMore(
    people = Single(3),
    things = Single(4),
    happy  = Single(true)
)

val m2 = TotalsMore(
    people = Split(3, 30),
    things = Split(4, 40),
    happy  = Split(true, false)
)
```

The data class declaration gives errors:

```
error: one type argument expected for class Splittable<T>
    data class TotalsMore<S : Splittable>(
                              ^
error: type arguments are not allowed for type parameters
        val people : S<Int>,
                      ^
error: type arguments are not allowed for type parameters
        val things : S<Int>,
                      ^
error: type arguments are not allowed for type parameters
        val happy  : S<Boolean>
                      ^
```

So it appears I cannot pass a higher-kinded type as a type parameter. Bummer.

I can decouple the two generics:

```
data class TotalsMore<SInt : Splittable<Int>,
                      SBoolean: Splittable<Boolean>>(
    val people : SInt,
    val things : SInt,
    val happy  : SBoolean
)
```

This works, but it makes it even more obvious that you can mix and match Single and Split, which I want to forbid:

```
val WRONG = TotalsMore(
    people = Single(3),
    things = Single(4),
    happy  = Split(true, false)
)
```

I would like every object of those data classes to either be made of all Single values, or all Split values, not a mix and match.

Can I express it using Kotlin's types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Totals` class requires a generic type parameter, but you don't specify one in the constuctor your example. The way that works is with type inference: the Kotlin compiler figures the generic type out from the other parameters. The reason you can mix `Single` and `Split` in your first `WRONG` example is that the compiler sees the two arguments and infers the common supertype from them. So you're actually constructing a `Totals<Splittable<Int>>`.

If you'd specify a subtype explicitly, you wouldn't be able to mix:

```
val WRONG = Totals<Single<Int>>(
    people = Single(3),
    things = Split(4, 40) /**  Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Split<Int> but Single<Int> was expected */
)
```

So what you want to do is to accept the subclasses of `Splittable` but not `Splittable` itself as a generic parameter.

You can achieve that with an additional interface for your subclasses and an additional [generic constraint](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-constraints) with a `where`-clause:

```
sealed class Splittable<T>

interface ConcreteSplittable

data class Single<T>(val single: T) : Splittable<T>(), ConcreteSplittable

data class Split<T>(val before: T, 
                    val after : T) : Splittable<T>(), ConcreteSplittable

data class Totals<SInt : Splittable<Int>>(
    val people : SInt,
    val things : SInt
) where SInt : ConcreteSplittable

val t1 = Totals<Single<Int>>(
    people = Single(3),
    things = Single(4)
)

val t2 = Totals(
    people = Split(3, 30),
    things = Split(4, 40)
)

val WRONG = Totals( /** Type parameter bound for SInt in constructor Totals<SInt : Splittable<Int>>(people: SInt, things: SInt) where SInt : ConcreteSplittable is not satisfied: inferred type Any is not a subtype of Splittable<Int> */
    people = Single(3),
    things = Split(4, 40)
)
```

As for the second part, I don't think that's quite possible. As you noted, type arguments are not allowed for type parameters.

Unfortunately, you can also not introduce a third type parameter `S` and restrict `SInt` and `SBool` to both the common type `S` and to `Splittable<Int>` or `Splittable<Bool>` respectively.

```
data class TotalsMore<S, SInt, SBool>
(
    val people : SInt,
    val things : SInt,
    val happy  : SBool
) where S : ConcreteSplittable, 
  SInt : S, 
  SInt : Splittable<Int>, /** Type parameter cannot have any other bounds if it's bounded by another type parameter */
  SBool : S,
  SBool : Splittable<Boolean> /** Type parameter cannot have any other bounds if it's bounded by another type parameter */
```

What you could do, is to create "safe" type aliases, like this:

```
data class TotalsMore<SInt : Splittable<Int>, SBool : Splittable<Boolean>> (
    val people : SInt,
    val things : SInt,
    val happy  : SBool )

typealias SingleTotalsMore = TotalsMore<Single<Int>, Single<Boolean>>

typealias SplitTotalsMore = TotalsMore<Split<Int>, Split<Boolean>>

val s = SingleTotalsMore(
    people = Single(3),
    things = Single(4),
    happy  = Single(true) )
```

Creating a mixed `TotalsMore` would still be possible though.

Comment: Oh, I see. By requiring both the superclass and the interface, I forbid the superclass alone from fulfilling the contract. What about the second part, where I combine Int and Boolean? (The second part was actually the crux of my question, but I got derailed with the first example.)

Comment: Ok, I wanted to see if that answers your first question, before trying to answer the second. I don't think what you're trying to do in the second part is fully possible. As you noted you cannot use a type argument on a type parameter. You also cannot add a third generic parameter to restrict the others to the same type without loosing their arguments. Best I can think of is to create type aliases. I'll update my answer.